# Oracle 12c modifying records in child table that includes insert, update, delete

Tags: sql, oracle12c

My first post here. Here's what i'm trying to do and i'm simplifying for this question. I have 2 tables.

Companies

```
--------------------------------
| COMPANY_ID  |  NAME          |
--------------------------------
| 1           |  Google        |
| 2           |  Santas Factory|
| 3           |  Pied Piper    |
--------------------------------
```

Employees

```
------------------------------------------------------
| EMPLOYEE_ID  |  COMPANY_ID  |  NAME                |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1            | 1            |  Larry Page          |
| 2            | 1            |  Sergey Brin         |
| 3            | 2            |  Santa Claus         |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a PLSQL that will insert with type objects. My question is if i have an type object of the same company what is the best practice in possibly updating, deleting or inserting to the child table?
Example payload:

```
Company_id: 1
Name: Google
Employees:
    |__ Name: Larry Single Page
    |__ Name: Sundar Pichai
```

How should I,

1. update larry Page
2. delete sergey brin (sorry sergey)
3. insert sundar pichai
   or is it even possible?

Thanks,
Allen

Comment: What do you mean when you say "type object of the same company"?  I'm not following.  Based on your questions, you would just update the Employees table specifying the `EMPLOYEE_ID`.

Comment: 1 How do you know that Lary Page is the same person as Larry Single Page?
2. Where is your payload stored? You can query for employees not in your payload and then delete them.
3. Employees that don't exist in the table can just be inserted.

Comment: *"I have a PLSQL that will insert with type objects."* - Where is it? We can't see

Comment: @msturek the problem is the employee id is not part of the object parameter. I will only have a list of names in this case.

Comment: @boyzers 1. I won't know unless i compared the name and company  id in this case. 2. what do you mean by payload? if you mean the object parameter to the PLSQL, it is retrieved from a different API and passed to the PLSQL, 3. I did consider that approach. This question is to ask whether that is an acceptable/best practice in oracle because i'm still rather novice in this platform.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I did not put the PLSQL because that is the part that is the part that i'm hoping to be answered.

Comment: The current state of the table structure is a flat table with employee_name1, employee_name2, employee_name3. This is an effort to normalize the schema.

Comment: @Allen, cant there be more than one employee with the same name in the company? For payload, I was using your term with regards to the sample data. Your final solution will examine the records and check if it already exists. If it doesn't - add it. If not, update it.